# Flutter AnimatedList - Adding a CurvedAnimation to a SlideTransition

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've managed to get to a point where I have an `AnimatedList` which will slide in newly added items. A `Dismissible` widget that wraps my list items controls the remove animation. My question is how can I add some sort of animation curve to the `SlideTransition` so that I can control how the new list item appears when it slides in. Here's where I'm at so far:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final checklists = Provider.of<Checklists>(context);

return AnimatedList(
  key: listKey,
  initialItemCount: checklists.lists.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i, animation) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: CurvedAnimation(parent: ).drive(child)  // <- this line needs changing
      child: _buildListItem(checklists.lists[i], i),          
    );
  },      
);
}
```

I'm not sure what to do with the `position` argument. Previously for the standard `SlideTransition` I was simply using

```
animation.drive(Tween(begin: Offset(0.2, 0), end: Offset(0.0, 0))),
```

which works fine, but is lacking a curve ease. Any ideas?

**Edit**
Heres the complete .dart file for clarity as well as where I insert a new item from the parent widget:

```
GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> recentListsAnimationKey = GlobalKey();

class RecentLists extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecentListsState createState() => _RecentListsState();
}

class _RecentListsState extends State<RecentLists>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Widget _buildListItem(Checklist list, int listIndex) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: ObjectKey(list.id),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      background: Container(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.delete,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (ctx) => ListItemsScreen(list.id),
            ),
          );
        },
        title: Text(list.name),
        leading: Checkbox(
          value: list.completed,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              list.completed = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        _onDeleteList(list, listIndex);
      },
    );
  }

  void _onDeleteList(Checklist list, int listIndex) {
    Provider.of<Checklists>(context).deleteList(list.id);
    recentListsAnimationKey.currentState
        .removeItem(listIndex, (_, __) => Container());

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'UNDO',
          onPressed: () {
            Provider.of<Checklists>(context).undoDeleteList(list, listIndex);
            recentListsAnimationKey.currentState
                .insertItem(listIndex, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100));
          },
        ),
        content: Text(
          'List deleted',
          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> _position;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _position = Tween(
      begin: Offset(0.5, 0),
      end: Offset(0.0, 0),
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Curves.decelerate,
      ),
    );
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final checklists = Provider.of<Checklists>(context);

    return AnimatedList(
      key: recentListsAnimationKey, 
      initialItemCount: checklists.lists.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i, animation) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: _position,
          child: _buildListItem(checklists.lists[i], i),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is where I insert new items into the list. No slide animation is shown.

```
void createNewList(BuildContext context) {
  if (nameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
    Provider.of<Checklists>(context).addList(nameController.text);
    recentListsAnimationKey.currentState.insertItem(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    nameController.clear();
   }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Animation.drive](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Animation/drive.html) function with a [CurveTween](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/CurveTween-class.html) chained to your offset Tween. Your itemBuilder should look like this:

```
itemBuilder: (ctx, i, animation) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: animation.drive(Tween(begin: Offset(2, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
            .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.elasticInOut))),
      child: _buildListItem(checklists.lists[i], i),          
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Flutter`, Animation just a class which change data from start to end based on percent provided from AnimationController. You have to prepare `position` which instance of `Animation<Offset>`.

```
class DemoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoWidgetState createState() => _DemoWidgetState();
}

class _DemoWidgetState extends State<DemoWidget>with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> _position;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final checklists = Provider.of<Checklists>(context);

    return AnimatedList(
      key: listKey,
      initialItemCount: checklists.lists.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i, animation) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: _position,
          child: _buildListItem(checklists.lists[i], i),          
        );
      },      
    );
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    _position = Tween(begin: Offset(0.2, 0), end: Offset(0.0, 0)).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.decelerate));
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for the initial items in the list, but when I add an item it does not animate. How do I animate adding items to the list?

Comment: :/ Please ask the new question and post this link here. Or you could control animation by the `_controller`.

Comment: I've edited my question to show more code to provide better context. The slide animation now works when the list is initially loaded, but when new items are added there is no slide animation.